# Server.Transfer() in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

it should be a simple question but I can't figure it out on my own.

I have a page with the path

```
www.example.com/foo/bar.aspx
```

And I need to Server.Transfer() from this page to

```
www.example.com/bla.aspx
```

the problem is if I do `Server.Transfer("bla.aspx")` I get an exception

`The file '/foo/bla.aspx' does not exist.` which is true.

If I do `Server.Transfer("/bla.aspx")` I get

`System.Threading.ThreadAbortException = {Unable to evaluate expression.}`

How can I get there? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the tilde (~) to refer to the root of the directory tree:

`Server.Transfer("~/bla.aspx")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a relative reference.

Try this:

Server.Transfer("~/bla.aspx")